# Parallel deployment with Tomcat7 using Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, tomcat7

I'm using the last version of Jenkis to deploy my application in a parallel way.

I have my application named app##1198.war as example.
I have no idea how to configure Jenkis to be able to deploy parallel war.
Using the configuration that I used before, with normal war file,  I got this error message:

***Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - No context exists for path /AppName##1198***

I have no clue how to fix this.
Thanks a lot for any useful advice

**UPDATE**

I think it's related to this ticker opened in Jira:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19564?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab

Comment: Since you are using Cargo, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25157554/957103

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in [Get maven to do parallel deployments to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26296237/957103), if you use maven as build tool you can use the [tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/) for this usecase :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/WebappName##${maven.build.timestamp}</path>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <username>tomcat</username>
                <password>tomcat</password>
                <update>true</update>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

As you can see the version is specified in the `path` element, based on the build timestamp in this example.

If you do not want to keep all the older version running in tomcat need to set `undeployOldVersions="true"` in your `$TOMCAT/conf/server.xml` `<Host>` element.